# How to print the results of a return method without using static or any static methods in Java

Tags: java, static

I am currently new to Java and need help. So i am suppose to create three methods to my sorting code without using "static". The three methods I am suppose to use are myRandom, to create an array of random numbers, mySort, to sort the array from highest to lowest, and printArray, to print the array. The problem is I do not know how to print the array after it has been sorted. Does the print method not work? This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class SortAnimate6
{ 
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int numbers[] = new int[10];

        System.out.println("The array original:");



        System.out.println("The array generated:");


    }

    public int [] myRandom (int[] numbers)
    {
       Random random = new Random();
       for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
           numbers[i] = random.nextInt(20); 
       return numbers;
    }

    public  void printArray(int[] list)
    {
         for (int counter = 0; counter < list.length; counter++)
             System.out.print(list[counter] + " ");
         System.out.println();
    }

    public int[] mySort (int[] numbers)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<numbers.length; j++)
            {
                if(numbers[i] < numbers[j])
                {
                    int temp = numbers[i];
                    numbers[i] = numbers[j];
                    numbers[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return numbers;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods printArray and mySort are not static, so they belong to the class.

I will give you part of the answer....

```
SortAnimate6 me = new SortAnimate6();
System.out.println("The array original:");
me.printArray(numbers);
```

Hopefully that will give you some things to try, and keep going.

Comment: Not static so they belong to an *instance.*

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing your code it appears that you need to be calling the methods that you're wanting to use. For example, if you want to call my sort you will need to pass the int array into the method by typing

```
mySort(myPassedIntArrayVariable);
```

You can also use the return statement you're in to set new variables inside your Main method. For example you could store the sort in a new variable such as

```
int[] storageArray = mySort(myPassedIntArrayVariable);
```

Hope this helps. Comment if this does not help your issue.

Comment: I kinda understand. I need to call my sorting and printing method into my main method. Got that. However, i am confused with how to go about it. Do I go into mySort method and create something like "mySort(numbers[i]);" ? Also, do I need to call MyRandom?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not rigid on using 3 methods you mentioned then you should go for this simple code

convert array to list with

```
Arrays.asList(yourArray);

Now simple use collections.sort(resultList)

Lastly iterate on list to print each number with sysout . Thats it
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call any of those methods without creating an instance of SortAnimate6 to call them on.